# Error 0x80131500 when developin windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have this issue when trying to run a simple windows phones application - application is not running and gets stuck while trying to connect to the emulator. No other information is supplied except for the error number - 0x80131500.

I have searched a solution for the problem for a long time and everyone who ran into this problem solved it in a way that doesn't match my situation: 
some had windows 8.1 preview installed - I have windows 8.1 pro installed.
some had VS2012 - I have VS2013. 
some didn't have hyper-v installed or running - I checked running services and hyper v is installed and running (after setting the bios to allow virtualization).

If anyone has an idea, I will appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I had this a while back and updateing everything worked for me (win 8.1 and VS2012..not 13 :() Maybe try VS2012 Update 4 and see if it happens there too.    have you read this one: http://blog.procesium.us/2013/08/windows-phon-8-emulator-compatbility.html

Comment: yea maybe i'll try it. the link you provided is for people with Windows 8 preview. Many people running this OS had this problem and the solution was always "upgrade to Win 8 pro. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've tried downgrading to Vs2012 but now having a different problem: Installation of windows phone 8 SDK gets stuck when trying to install Windows phone 7.1 SDK assemblies. Also couldn't find a solution online.